# How to convert form text to image when submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

[image]
Hi Guys, I'm trying to solved this kind of form that when I clicked the submit button in a form the output will become image/picture and all the data that are in the fields will be compiled too in the image.

I would love and appreciate your kindness if you could help me to solve this kind of problem.

Please check image as my sample.

Comment: please show what have you tried so far

Comment: Try something like this tutorial http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagestring.php

Comment: On submit, copy all the form contents to a single div, run [html2canvas](http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/) on the div and post the image.

Comment: Sorry Abhishek Ghosh, no codes yet. I just look and tried to see if it can really be created with your help and other guys here. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Client-side you can use [canvas](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Drawing_text) to draw a text as an image.

```js
var canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
document.querySelector('form').addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
  var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')
    , line = 0;
  
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  [].forEach.call(event.srcElement.querySelectorAll('label'), function(label) {
    ctx.fillText(label.textContent + label.querySelector('input').value, 20, (++line) * 20);
  });
});
```

```css
form, canvas { width: 500px }
canvas { height: 200px }
form > * { display: block }
form > * + * { margin-top: .5em; }
form input { width: 100% }
```

```html
<form>
  <label>Name: <input name="name"></label>
  <label>Address: <input name="address"></label>
  <button>draw</button>
</form>
<canvas></canvas>
```

Comment: wow, really great! I really appreciate your help. This will be a big help. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Copy the textarea contents to a div, run html2canvas and upload the image via ajax:

```js
$('#submit').click(function() {
  var abc = $('#text1').val();
  var def = $('#text2').val();
  var ghi = $('#text3').val();
  $('#container').html('<div class = text1>' + abc + '</div><div class = text2>' + def + '</div><div class = text3>' + ghi + '</div>');
  html2canvas($('#container'), {
    onrendered: function(canvas) {
      myImage = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
      $('#image').append(canvas);
      //$.ajax({
      //data: myImage
      // ....
    }
  });
});
```

```css
#image {
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 10px;
  width: 100px; 
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2canvas/0.4.1/html2canvas.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="text1">ABC</textarea>
<textarea id="text2">DEF</textarea>
<textarea id="text3">GHI</textarea>
<button id="submit">Submit</button>
<br>Your text will appear here ->
<br>
<div id="container"></div><br>
Your image will appear here ->
<br>
<div id="image"></div>
```

Comment: Hi, could you please make me this not looping when I clicked submit? and is it possible to share it to facebook without saving? thank you

Comment: If, by 'not looping' you mean not displaying the HTML of the form, just add this line `      $('#container').hide();` first up in the `onrendered' function.  As for posting to Facebook without saving, delete the line `$('#image').append(canvas);` and then pass the variable `myImage` to the `picture` element in your Graph API function.